# Wicket - Back button after form submit

Tags: java, forms, wicket

I have a new problem with a Form and the BACK button.

Take this kind of FORM:

```
public SearchSomethingForm() {
super(ORSAWebConstants.FORM);
setModel(new CompoundPropertyModel<Void>(this));

add(section01Panel);
add(section02Panel);
add(section03Panel);
add(new SubmitButton());
```

}

As you see, I don't have a property model base on a single Object.

Inside the form I only add some panel with some INPUT inside. For Example:

```
private String name;
protected void onInitialize() {
 super.onInitialize();
 final TextField<String> foo = new TextField<String> ("name",new PropertyModel<String>(this,"name"));
 add (foo);
}
```

Every Panel code has something like that. Some input with a BIND to a local Property.

Then in FORM SUBMIT, I can read the value with

```
section01Panel.getName();
```

**PROBLEM**

After the form submit, I open a new Page with result. I want a BACK button to the FORM's Page with every pre-entered field already compiled so the user has only to change a portion of form to make a new search.

Without a specific PropertyModel, I can't compile the Object with its property mapped on form fields. The Form doesn't Know which kind of FIELD will be added.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for storing your state inside various components instead of a single dedicated state object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some test I discovered that Wicket can pass entire page from pages so when I call the new page, I pass the form page:

```
SheetPage page = new SheetPage("SheetPage", idPojo,FormPage.this);
setResponsePage(page);
```

In the SheetPage I will have a LINK to the previous page:

```
public SheetPage(String title, String idPojo, final FormPage fPage) {
    Link back = new Link("back"){
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       public void onClick() {
         setResponsePage(fPage);
      };
    };
}
```

When I return to FormPage, I will find the page as was before opening the sheet page with form entirely pre-compiled. Awesome!